# No titlebar or back button being generated sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a list and each item links to a different page when clicked on using push(). I am pushing them fine but when they do, they don't have the default titlebar or back button that should come with a page pushed on top of the current one. Any ideas? Here is my code:

View being pushed:

```
Ext.define('myApp.view.Appearances', {

extend: 'Ext.Panel',
xtype: 'Appearances',

config: {
    title: '<span class="logo"></span>',
    scrollable: 'vertical',
    tpl: [
        '<h1>Appearances</h1>'
    ]
}

});
```

Controller:

```
this.getMain().push({
            xtype: 'Appearances'
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use NavigationView for that: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.1.1/#!/api/Ext.navigation.View